# How to get Facebook Timeline images using ASP.NET MVC 5 and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor

I am developing a website with ASP .NET MVC 5 and am new to .NET MVC. On that website I have to display the users Timeline images. As of now, I am login with OWIN and accessing the images using JavaScript API. Is there way to get the user images using ASP.NET MVC 5 without using JavaScript?.

```
var x = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        x.Scope.Add("email");
        x.Scope.Add("user_photos");
        x.Scope.Add("publish_actions");
        x.Scope.Add("user_posts");
        x.AppId = "*";
        x.AppSecret = "**";
        x.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                foreach (var claim in context.User)
                {
                    var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                    string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));

                }

            }
        };

        x.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(x);
```

The same as done using Facebook canvas. But, I need for website. Please let me know the way is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook SDK for .Net http://facebooksdk.net/docs/
Use the Access Token that you have added to the claims to make further Graph Api calls through the FacebookClient.
Code snippet from the docs:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic me = fb.Get("me");
var id = me.id;
var name = me.name;
```